# Modificar url y agregarle el ID con JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Estoy realizando un programa pero me estanqué, lo que quiero lograr hacer es que mi url me marque el ID del usuario, ya hice la consulta.

Mas o menos quiero que quede así:

`MIURL.com/?id= (AQUI IRIA EL ID DEL USUARIO)`

Finalizado
Sería la prueba final

`MIURL.com/?id= 85`

```
            var id = Element.getAttribute('id')  // Aquí estoy haciendo la consulta donde si me devuelve el ID
               //Este sería el código para que funcione el botón.

           var text = document.createElement('div'); 
           text.innerHTML = '<a href="informacion.php?id="><button> VER MAS </button></a>'
           infowincontent.appendChild(text);
           infowincontent.appendChild(document.createElement('br'));
```

Comment: Donde esta el problema?, como obtener el id? como agregar ese id que ya tienes en una url?, concatenando la variable diría yo pero no queda clara tu pregunta.

Comment: Necesitas concatenar: `'texto=' + variable + 'más texto'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Debería funcionarte así (Mira las comillas invertidas al inicio y final del string)

```
text.innerHTML = `<a href="informacion.php?id=${id}"><button> VER MAS </button></a>`
```

Comment: se conocen como[Backstick o plantillas literales](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

Comment: GRACIAS MI BRO! 
me funciono, te lo agradezco de todo corazón!

Comment: Con mucho gusto ;)

Answer (score 0):

Para escribir el código HTML deberías crear otro elemento `<a>` y dentro de el poner su contenido. Te debería quedar algo así:

```js
              const id = 30 //Id de ejemplo

              const wrapper = document.createElement('div'); //Creamos el Div
              const text = document.createElement('a'); //Creamos el link
              const button = document.createElement('button') //Creamos el botón
               button.textContent = "Ver más" //Texto al botón               
text.setAttribute('href', `informacion.php?id=${id}`) //Le ponemos el atributo al link
              text.appendChild(button) //Le agregamos el botón al texto
              wrapper.appendChild(text) // Le agregamos el texto al div
              document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(wrapper) //Insertamos el div
```

*edit*: la etiqueta `<a>` no sería necesaria en este caso (se puede poner el link en el botón), pero lo dejo así para respetar el ejemplo dado

Comment: No lo puse a prueba, pero seria un respuesta bastante útil, de igual forma muchas gracias por comentar te lo agradesco!